# Multiple events get different instances of a field declared in singleton?

Tags: c#, events

**Edit: My bad, no strage events behavior. Error was somewhere else in code. Thx everybody for help. Please ignore this question**

Please can someone explain to me what is happening here. I'm experiencing an unexpected event behaviour.

There is a singleton class:

```
internal class QueueListener
{
   private static readonly object QueueChangeLock = new object();
   private readonly List<IQueuedJobExecutioner> jobsQueue = new List<IQueuedJobExecutioner>();

  // Here comes singleton private constructor, Instance property, all classic.
  // Important line in constructor is this:
  QueueManager.NewJobQueued += NewJobQueuedHandler;

private void NewJobQueuedHandler(object sender, NewJobQueuedEventArgs args)
        {
            lock (QueueChangeLock)
            {
                // This is the problematic place, note this!
                jobsQueue.Add(args.QueuedJobExecutioner);
            }
        }  
}
```

Now there is a second class:

```
public class QueueManager
{
   public static event NewJobQueuedEventHandler NewJobQueued;

   protected void RaiseNewJobQueuedEvent(IQueuedJobExecutioner queuedJobExecutioner)
        {
            if (NewJobQueued != null)
            {
                NewJobQueued(this, new NewJobQueuedEventArgs { QueuedJobExecutioner = queuedJobExecutioner });
            }
        }
}
```

Both classes reside on a server. Via WCF calls client executes sth like `new QueueManager().MyMethod()`, which calls `RaiseNewJobQueuedEvent`.

Everything works fine, however if two events are raised almost at the same time, I see in debugger the following at the problematic place (see comment in QueueListener):

1. First event comes. jobsQueue has no members.
2. jobsQueue.Add() is executed. jobsQueue has 1 member.
3. Second event comes. jobsQueue has no members! How? It's in a singleton and we just added a member!
4. jobsQueue.Add() is executed. jobsQueue has 1 member. Again. Member added in step 2 has been lost.

Not judging the design itself (it has some "historical" reasons), why exactly is this happening? Is this expected behavior and event somehow gets at some point a snapshot of jobsQueue or this is nonesense and I'm just missing some part of the puzzle?

Edit:
I'd say it is a singleton, and is implemented like this (these lines were omitted in original post):

```
class QueueListener
{
  private static readonly object SyncRoot = new object();
  private QueueListener()
        {
//...
        }

        public static QueueListener Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (instance == null)
                {
                    lock (SyncRoot)
                    {
                        if (instance == null)
                        {
                            instance = new QueueListener();
                        }
                    }
                }

                return instance;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Your `QueueListener` isn't a singleton.

Answer (score 0):

Yuval is correct, your class is not a singleton.  A singleton is created when you have a public static method to create an instance and a private constructor.  The private constructor ensures that the only way to create an instance is through the public method.

Please see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Your `QueueListener` class is not actually a singleton. What that means for you is that you are creating multiple instances of it.  To fix that you have to add the `static` keyword in the class declaration and declare a `static` constructor as well. Try changing your class to what is shown below:

```
internal static class QueueListener
{
       private static readonly object QueueChangeLock = new object();
       private static readonly List<IQueuedJobExecutioner> jobsQueue = new List<IQueuedJobExecutioner>();

    // This is the singleton constructor that will be called
    static QueueListener()
    {
      // Here comes singleton private constructor, Instance property, all classic.
      // Important line in constructor is this:
      QueueManager.NewJobQueued += NewJobQueuedHandler;
    }

    // Rest of class code...
}
```